# Add app.config file for console application in Visual studio for mac

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio, app-config

I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46156904/how-to-use-appsettings-in-net-for-mac) to add a config file for console project. I have successfully added app.config but do not know how to use it. I cannot reference `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;`

It produces the following error,

> The typename or namespace name 'ConfigurationManager' does not exist in the 'System Configuration(' are you missong and assembly reference?)'

I right-clicked on dependencies but cannot see the option 'add references'.

Comment: What do you mean you can not reference? Please provide the error message and more information.

Comment: Updated the compiler error

Comment: You need to add a reference to `assembly System.Configuration.dll` in your project. See  [The name 'ConfigurationManager' does not exist in the current context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274852/the-name-configurationmanager-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context).

Comment: I am working on Mac and I don't see an option 'Add references' but 'add packages' that takes me to nuget. I am a kind of new to C# and working with mac.

Answer (score 3):

Right click on project -> Click **"Add"** -> Click **"Add Nuget Packages"**

[image]

This will open up a new window to add Nuget packages.

Type **"System.Configuration"** in search box. You will see a package **"System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager"**.

Add this package, this will resolve your problem.

[image]

Comment: For Mac users that'll be this command: `dotnet add package System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager`